# Can't get program to display correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I'm using Python 3.11 to create a laser counter on a raspberry pi 4. I'm using a code that was build for python 3.7 and have made some updates to it. However when the program is run it just boots up a black screen and does not display the count numbers I need it to. The laser and counter is working right when I just run those without the display. It just won't display.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import pygame
import sys
# pygame code. this is the code to display the estimated takt time on the monitor
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
# These numbers will be based on your monitor size
display_width = 1060
display_height = 700
sizefont = (display_width + display_height) / 4.25
# Determines the display windows color
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255,)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height), pygame.RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.set_caption('Laser')
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monaco", int(sizefont))
pygame.init()
newt = time.time() + 60
# Set GPIO mod Board or BCM
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
LSGPIO = 18
# 18BCM/Pin 12 (Pin and BCM will vary based on wiring)
GPIO.setup(LSGPIO, GPIO.IN)
# Define counter and loop variables
icount_signal = 0
xsave = 0
# Define time variables
Time1 = time.perf_counter()
Time2 = time.perf_counter()
TimeE = Time2 - Time1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        while True:
            if GPIO.input(LSGPIO) == 0:
                Time1 = time.perf_counter()
            if GPIO.input(LSGPIO) == 1:
                Time2 = time.perf_counter()
            if GPIO.input(LSGPIO):
                xsave = 1
            else:
                if xsave == 1:
                    if TimeE < .5:
                        xsave = 0
                        TimeE = Time2 - Time1
                    if TimeE > .5:
                        icount_signal += 1
                        print('Detection = %s' % icount_signal)
                        # print('%s'%TimeE)
                        xsave = 0
                        TimeE = Time2 - Time1
                        Time1 = time.perf_counter()
                    if time.time() > newt:
                        takt = int(icount_signal * 60)
                        gameDisplay.fill(pygame.Color("black"))
                        text1 = myfont.render(str(takt), 1, blue)
                        gameDisplay.blit(text1, (0, 0))
                        pygame.display.update()
                        icount_signal = 0
                        newt = time.time() + 60
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Measurement stopped by User")
GPIO.cleanup()
pygame.quit()
```

I have updated the needed functions that were deprecated like time.clock(). I have poured over forums and documents to see if anyone else has had similar issue or if there were more functions that were not working properly. Updated python and the related modules. I'm hoping someone else can see what I can't.

Comment: Start small, try to display the bare minimum. Then start adding to it and see at what point it fails.

Comment: You're calling `pygame.init()` twice.  Also note that `if GPIO.input(LSGPIO) == 1:` and `if GPIO.input(LSGPIO):` do exactly the same thing.  I don't think your `if` logic does what you think it does.

Comment: Is it possible that `xsave` never becomes equal to 1 and/or  `TimeE` is never greater than `0.5`? If so, you'll never enter the branch that prints something.

I'd suggest checking all these if statements once again, they seem a bit complex and hence error-prone

Comment: Thank you guys for you comments! They pointed me in the right direction and I was able to adjust the code and get it to work. Your guys comments help solve a 2 week issue!